# wget error: bad header line

Tags: linux, bash, wget, openwrt

Why doesn't this work?:
`wget -q -U Mozilla "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot" -O - | tr '\n' ' '`

p.s.: and under openwrt 10.03:
`# wget "http://slashdot.org/" -O -`
`Connecting to slashdot.org (216.34.181.45:80)`
`wget: bad header line: slash_LOG_DATA: shtml`
`$`

Comment: The `tr '\n' ' '` has nothing to do with it. `wget` is getting an error when trying to download the file.

Comment: `wget -q -U Mozilla "http://slashdot.org/" -O - | tr '\n' ' '`  works perfectly for me

Comment: What error does `wget -q -U Mozilla "http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot" -O -` give? What is your expected result of doing that whole command with `tr` and what do you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
wget "http://slashdot.org/" -O -
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Server: Apache/1.3.42 (Unix) mod_perl/1.31  
SLASH_LOG_DATA: shtml  
...
```

`wget` performs bad on the third line of the header, seems like a bug to me. I would suggest reporting it.

Furthermore, I would suspect that site to act weird as they are using old standards...

Answer (score 0):

This still happens and isn't a fault or bug. The wget command will create a file - whether you download something or not. So the second time you issue the same command the file is already there.

This happens for instance when you use wget in a BeagleBone to pass weather info to your website for logging purposes:

eg.:

```
wget "http://www.mysite.com/tempinfo.php?temp=15"
```

**NOTE:* (Filename starts with first letter after the last "/" and ends with last letter or first blank)

This will run OK the first time but the second time it will produce named error because `wget` tries again to create a file with the name `"tempinfo.php?temp=15"`.

What you could do is (re)direct the dummy file to dummy output ;-)

So the proper command in this case would be:

```
wget "http://www.mysite.com/tempinfo.php?temp=15" -O /dev/null
```